# Networked logger for C using Multicast UDP?

Tags: c, linux, logging, udp, multicast

Any reccomendations of a libary which I can call from my Linux (C) app to send simple log messages to anyone who happens to be listening on the network, using Multicast UDP?

Comment: What have you found when searching e.g. Google? Have you tried any of those?

Comment: Options seem to be log4cpp or syslog, which dont seem to quite fit / are too heavy. Alternatively, I could write my own, but only QT 4.8 has multicast, and I dont fancy having to hack out loads of socket code myself.

Comment: Would syslog not fit ? You'd decouple the log delivery from your app - all you do is call 1 function - and configure syslog to deliver the logs whereever - e.g. a multicast destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a library to *send* a multicast packet.  Sending a UDP message to a multicast socket is only marginally more complicated than sending one to a unicast address.

In particular you'll need to use `setsockopt` to set the `IP_MULTICAST_TTL` of your packets.

The receiving side is slightly harder - you have to join a particular multicast group using `setsockopt` with `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` to be able to receive the messages sent to it.

These options are all documented in `man 7 ip` .

Answer (score 0):

As you asked "Any reccomendations of a libary" I consider you dont want just the standard c library because I never see anyone ask if someone recommends c library to c development. So obviously you dont need any thing more than c library but my answer fits your question perfectly or, maybe, the question is not so good.

You can use the excellent ZeroMQ and EPGM protocol (encapsulated inside UDP)

[zmq_pgm - ØMQ reliable multicast transport using PGM](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-pgm)

in the server side

```
void *context = zmq_init(1);
assert(context);
void *broadcast = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
assert(broadcast);
rc = zmq_bind(broadcast, "epgm://192.168.0.123:5555");
assert(rc==0);
rc = s_send(broadcast, "Hello world!");
assert(rc==0);
```

in client side:

```
void *context = zmq_init(1);
assert(context);
void *watch = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
assert(watch);    
rc = zmq_connect(watch, "epgm://192.168.0.123:5555");
assert(rc==0);
char *message = s_receive(watch);
assert(message);
```

Comment: I believe he wants to use arbitrary UDP messages, not something with a higher-level wrapper.

Comment: @Alnitak How do you propose that OP should implement his logging facility _without_ adding some extra information? The most naïve implementation, all data in the packet is logging data to be written to file/the console, is always possible but it offers very little control.

Comment: @HonkyTonk ZeroMQ as described here isn't providing any structure to the content, it's just wrapping some network level goodness (i.e. multicast handling and reliable transport) into an API.  The developer still has to define the content of the messages.